# FullCalendar.js not showing events in IE 10 and FF 21.0

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I created a calendar with [FullCalendar.js](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and it's working fine on Chrome (v.27) but not working on IE 10 e FF 21.0. Here the code that renders the events:

```
    <?php
        $user_selected = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : $_SESSION[$pre_ssn.'userid'];
        // [...]

        $get_dati_calendar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendario_fonderia WHERE user_id = $user_selected ");
        $eventi = '[';
        while ($calendar = mysql_fetch_array($get_dati_calendar)) {
            $coloring = ($calendar['eur_gr'] != '') ? ", className: 'fc-event-done'" : '';
            $dati_cal = ($calendar['eur_gr'] != '') ? $calendar['grammi'].' gr.\n'.$calendar['eur_gr'].' €/gr' : $calendar['grammi'].' gr.' ; 
            $eventi .= "{ title: '".$dati_cal."', start: new Date('".$calendar['data']."'), allDay: true ".$coloring." },";
        }
        echo ($eventi != '[') ? substr($eventi, 0, -1)."]\n" : "[]\n";
    ?>
```

And this is the full code (with at the end the php renderer):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    

    //datepicker
    jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker();

    // tabbed widget
    jQuery('.tabbedwidget').tabs();

    function shortAjax(file, mode, dati){
        var datiEx = jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: file+".php",
        data: "mode="+mode+"&"+dati,
        async: false}).responseText;
        return datiEx;
    }

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var eventi_gg = Array();

    var calendar = jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        firstDay: 1, // Start with Monday
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: false
        },
        buttonText: {
            prev: '&laquo;',
            next: '&raquo;',
            prevYear: '&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;',
            nextYear: '&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;',
            today: 'today'
        },
        monthNamesShort: [ "Gen", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mag", "Giu", "Lug", "Ago", "Sett", "Ott", "Nov", "Dic"],
        monthNames: [ "Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"],
        dayNames : ["Domenica", "Lunedì", "Martedì", "Mercoledì", "Giovedì", "Venerdì", "Sabato", "Domenica"],
        dayNamesShort : ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Giov", "Ven", "Sab", "Dom"],
        allDayText: "GIORNATA",
        titleFormat:{month:"MMMM yyyy",week:"d [ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'d MMM[ MMM] yyyy}",day:"dddd d MMM yyyy"},
        columnFormat:{month:"ddd",week:"dddd d/M",day:"dddd d MMMM"},
        buttonText: {
            prev: '&laquo;',
            next: '&raquo;',
            prevYear: '&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;',
            nextYear: '&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;',
            today: 'oggi'
        },
        selectable: false,
        editable: false,

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loader_layer').show();
            else $('#loader_layer').hide();
        },

        dayClick: function(start) {
            jQuery(this).append("<div style='text-align:center; position:relative; top:50%;' id='load-calendar'><img src='images/loaders/loader10-1.gif' /></div>");
            var oggi = date.getFullYear()+'-'+ ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);

            data_click = jQuery.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            data_click_short = jQuery.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd");
            giorno_click = jQuery.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "dd/MM");

            var numEventi = shortAjax("handler_fonderia", "check_event", "data="+data_click_short);
            //console.log(data_click_short+'-'+oggi);
            //&& data_click_short == oggi
            if(numEventi == 0 ){
                jQuery.alerts.dialogClass = 'alert-danger';
                jQuery.alerts.okButton = 'Prosegui';
                var deposito = shortAjax("handler_fonderia", "get_deposito", "id=");
                jPrompt('Grammi:', '', 'Aggiunta Grammi al '+giorno_click, function(grammi) {
                    if(grammi){
                        grammi = parseFloat(grammi);
                        //jAlert(grammi+' - '+deposito);/*
                        if(grammi <= deposito){
                        jQuery.alerts.okButton = 'Confermo';
                        jQuery.alerts.cancelButton = 'No, Annulla';
                          jConfirm('Stai per inserire <b>'+grammi+'</b> grammi per il giorno <b>'+giorno_click+'</b>.<br>Questi dati non possono più essere modificati. Confermi?', 'CONFERMA GRAMMI', function(conferma){
                            if(conferma){
                                var creaEvento = shortAjax("handler_fonderia", "add_grammi", "grammi="+grammi+"&data="+data_click+"&day="+data_click_short);
                                if(creaEvento == "true"){
                                    jQuery('#load-calendar').remove();
                                    var resdeposito = parseFloat(jQuery('#depositoVal').val()-grammi);
                                    var cumdeposito = parseFloat(jQuery('#depositoCum').val());
                                    var totdeposito = parseFloat(cumdeposito+grammi);
                                    jQuery('#totDeposito').val('Deposito: '+resdeposito.toFixed(1)+' gr.');
                                    jQuery('#totVenduto').val('Venduto: '+totdeposito.toFixed(1)+' gr.');
                                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                                        title: grammi + " gr.",
                                        start: start
                                    }, true);
                                }
                            }
                          });
                        }else{
                            jQuery('#load-calendar').remove();
                            jQuery.alerts.okButton = 'OK';
                            jAlert('I grammi che vuoi inserire sono superiori al deposito.<br>Richiedere un <a href="deposito.php">nuovo deposito</a> o inserire una grammatura inferiore.', 'Errore');
                        }
                    }jQuery('#load-calendar').remove();
                });


            }else if(numEventi == 0 && data_click_short < oggi){
                jQuery('#load-calendar').remove();
                jQuery.jGrowl("E' possibile inserire i grammi solo nel giorno corrente.", {header: '<span style="color:red; font-size:12px;">Attenzione</span>', life:8000});
            }

        },
        editable: false,
        events:
        <?php
            $get_dati_calendar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendario_fonderia WHERE user_id = $user_selected ");
            $eventi = '[';
            while ($calendar = mysql_fetch_array($get_dati_calendar)) {
                $coloring = ($calendar['eur_gr'] != '') ? ", className: 'fc-event-done'" : '';
                $dati_cal = ($calendar['eur_gr'] != '') ? $calendar['grammi'].' gr.\n'.$calendar['eur_gr'].' €/gr' : $calendar['grammi'].' gr.' ; 
                $eventi .= "{ title: '".$dati_cal."', start: new Date('".$calendar['data']."'), allDay: true ".$coloring." },";
            }
            echo ($eventi != '[') ? substr($eventi, 0, -1)."]\n" : "[]\n";
        ?>
    });


    function effectFadeIn() {
        jQuery('#ptDeposito').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500, effectFadeOut());
    }
    function effectFadeOut() {
        jQuery('#ptDeposito').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500, effectFadeIn());
    }

    <?= $effect_on ?>

});
```

Event gets written on the DB and everything works fine on that side.
Unfortunately I can't give you a link for this. I'll try to JSfiddle it.

***EDIT***

I tried to see if the problem was the PHP echoing so I tried writing directly the event in JS like this:

```
events: [{ title   : 'A', 
                        start   : new Date('2013-07-09 00:00:00'), 
                        allDay  : true, className: 'fc-event-done' }]
```

And it doesn't work, therefore the issue must be something else...

Comment: It would be great if you could JSfiddle'd it. But before starting looking your code: which version for FullCalendar/JQuery?

Comment: The issue seems to what regards to the date. See below answer.

Comment: Ok, However just encode your response. Just thrown everything in an array and json_encode after. Like:  `code`while ($calendar = mysql_fetch_array($get_dati_calendar)) {
   $eventi[] = array(
  'id' => $calendar['id'],'title' => ($calendar['eur_gr'] != '') ? $calendar['grammi'].' gr.\n'.$calendar['eur_gr'].' €/gr' : $calendar['grammi'].' gr.',
       'className' => ($calendar['eur_gr'] != '') ? ",className: 'fc-event-done'" : '',
       'start' => $calendar['data'],'end' => $calendar['data'],'allDay' => true);  
        } echo json_encode($eventi);`code`

Comment: Ok, guys we are allmost there, working in FF... Please don't give up now... :D

Comment: Have you tried json encoding? Which format r u using for store your start/end date? Check the compatibility between JQuery and Fullcalendar as well tho...

Comment: @simongus ok I'll try JSON encoding. But how? can you give an example?

Comment: Pretty much like my example before. You need to store all info in an array, per instance, and call json_encode($your_array);

Answer (score 1):

Look firefox error console. $user_selected nis not defined, php sent warning and sql error and break json code. Remember add json headers. And remember:

```
events:[,className: 'fc-event-done' ...
```

Is not correct, you need objects not arrays:

```
events: {className:'foo', etc...
```

Make an array in while and show with join(',') for correct concatenation.

Try it:

```
events:
    <?php
        $user_selected = 1; // ???
        $get_dati_calendar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendario_fonderia WHERE user_id = $user_selected ");
        $data = array();
        while ($calendar = mysql_fetch_array($get_dati_calendar)) {
            $data[] = "{
                title   : '".(($calendar['eur_gr']) ? $calendar['grammi'].' gr.\n'.$calendar['eur_gr'].' €/gr' : $calendar['grammi'].' gr.')."', 
                start   : new Date('".$calendar['data']."'), 
                allDay  : true 
                ".($calendar['eur_gr'] ? ", className: 'fc-event-done'" : "")." 
            }";
        }
        echo implode(',' $data);
    ?>
}
```

Or change for an array:

```
echo '['.implode(',' $data).']';
```

Comment: Tku, I'll test it tonite and let u know.

Answer (score 1):

I'v logged in FF console `new Date('2013-07-09 00:00:00')` and get this error `Date {Invalid Date}`. If you try convert your date to `ISO 8601` format, something like this `2013-07-09T19:10:00-04:00`, all should work fine.

UPD: why you try not return response in json format from server side?

Comment: Seems workig ok with FF! I'll check on IE tonight and let u know. What do you mean by "why you try not return response in json format from server side?"

Comment: You insert your php code into javascript as string. You can just create individual php file, in this file do all queries from db and return data in json format. In the js file you can write some function, get data with $.ajax() and set calendar events from server response. This solution is work well in all browsers. If you want to see example, just say.

Comment: You can use the property events to call an ajax request. `code` $('#calendar_daily').fullCalendar({events:{url:'yourfile.php', type: 'POST'}});`code`

Comment: Ok, it works fine in FF with the ISO date, but in IE nothing... As it's a protected file and area I'll try to remove the protection so you can see what happens. But that solved it for FF! I see no error in IE console...

Comment: Which version of IE you use? I'v tested in IE9 and IE10 - code worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load data in this datetime format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" it helps me. I'm using FullCaneldar in ASP.Net MVC C# project...